# How to fetch all Entity objects of a specific type in objectify 4?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have saved multiple objects of an entity type in datastore. Now i want to retrieve all entities of this type.
i am currently using

```
ofy().load.type(MyEntityType.Class).list()
```

But this operation looks time consuming.What could be the issues or is there an alternative to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try using ".iterable()" so the entites are fetched during the iteration and not all a t the same time

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? Did using `.iterable()` as suggested above solve the issue?

Comment: @markvgti i dint chnage my code, as somebody had suggested elsewhere in SO dat i need to actually see d result in Production not Dev Server.Yet to deploy.. Are you seeing this issue in prod.?